# Word for letters that aren't typographically similar

Tags: orthography, typography, handwriting

For example I, 1, or l (lowercase L) can be indistinguishable from one another depending on the persons writing style. The same for the number 0 and the letter O.

Is there a word for letters that are visually distinct and are not easily misread due to handwriting or character display?

Comment: in 3 words: "clearly identifiable letters".

Comment: Distinct, different.

Answer (score 1):

I might use *graphically dissimilar*.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to coin a new word, I would be okay with *heterographs.*